# Copy resulting fat jar to another target folder in Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have Spring boot project. Everything is built OK in `/target` folder but I'd like to change destination folder.
I tried to use `maven-jar-plugin` as described below but it copies only jar with compiled classes of project (small jar).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}/output/bin</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Instead I want to make Maven to copy **FAT jar**.
Maven builds FAT jar and puts the Jar to `/target` folder. How to change destination?

**UPDATE 1**

this is needed by project requirements - need to build folder structure with **properties**, **bash** scripts(as entry point) and **fat jar**:

[image]

Comment: Why do you like to change that?

Comment: Project requirements.

Comment: Of course I could do this by bash script in opposite case, but I'd lite do that by maven.

Comment: Sorry but that does not explain why it's needed? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise update original question

Comment: For such things I recommend to use the maven-assembly-plugin which can create such structures and it's easy to package into tar.gz/tar/zip etc. apart from that why do you need such structure?

Comment: @khmarbaise thx for advice, I'll check it out little later. I need this structure to make distribution easier to my raspberry pi.

Comment: Why not building an RPM for Raspi?

Comment: RPM? You mean Linux package? This is very new for me, never did that. But I'll try :-) thx. Any additional ideas? I'm new in Linux and open for new challenge

Comment: Linux package yes. On Raspian (Debian like on Raspi) installing via `rpm -i xyz.rpm` ...

Comment: The other question is to separate packaging and deployment on your Raspi ...

Comment: The other question is why you have located the application properties outside the spring boot jar ?

Comment: @khmarbaise for flexibility, testing on ci server, and re-configuring without complilation.

Comment: Testing on CI server should never need to externalize the configuration. Externalization the configuration is a good idea...and if you are on a CI server you should produce an artifact like I described either via maven-assembly-plugin or an RPM and deploy that via a different step (CI) not in Maven to your target machine...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                <outputDirectory>${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}/output/bin</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```